# Highlight.js with React.js syntax highlighting not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, syntax-highlighting, highlight.js

I am trying to use highlight.js with react but the syntax highlighting is now working.
I am trying to store the highlighted syntax inside a variable but the whole content is displayed without highlighting with highlight.js span tags.

```js
import React from "react";
import hljs from "highlight.js";

const test = `const test = require('test')`;
const tt = hljs.highlightAuto(test).value;


function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <pre>
        <code>{tt}</code>
      </pre>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [react-highlight](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-highlight) is built on top of highlight.js

Comment: Looks like it is out-dated now. Not getting updates from 2022